# Meteor Google Maps Retrieve Specific Results from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, meteor, google-geocoding-api

I'm trying to retrieve for example the formatted_address in Google Maps. I'm currently using Meteor and my code are as follows:

```
Template.searchResults.helpers({
    exampleMapOptions: function() {
        var lat = Session.get("lat") ? Session.get("lat") : 12;
        var lng = Session.get("lng") ? Session.get("lng") : -85; 

        if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
            var latlng = lat + "," +lng;
            var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latlng + "&sensor=false";
            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++) {
                    var address = data.results[i].formatted_address;
                    console.log(address);
                }
            });
            return {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                zoom: 10,

            };
        }
    }
});
```

However I am only able to retrieve some of the results. For example if i search "Hotels in Paris" and there were 20+ results, I was only able to retrieve only 4 or 5. Anyone would be kind enough to point me to the right directions? Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I can't see where you are requesting a search for "Hotels in paris", or anything - your query consists of a single point

Comment: [TextSearchRequests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=en#TextSearchRequests) should be used for queries such as "hotels in paris". The response will have a `result` array. You will have to call Place Details individually though to get the `formatted_address.